# can I custom a stream whose element is a struct

Tags: c++, stream

I got a struct type, let's say it looks like this:

```
struct Token {
  int type;
  char value[64];
};
```

and I want put objects of `Token` to a stream, and functions like `get()`, `peek()` all returns an object(or a reference/pointer)?

something like this:
`Token token = stream.get();` or
`Token* token = stream.get();`

Comment: That's not possible, but you could overload the `operator>>` function to read a `Token` object.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe specializing [`std::char_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) (or writing a custom replacement) for your type is what you want?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's probably not enough, as e.g. the [`get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) function reads a "character" from the underlying buffer, and that needs to be specialized as well (or maybe even reimplemented).

Comment: @reavenisadesk Can you please tell us what problem you're really trying to solve? Why do you need to get `Token` from the `get` or `peek` functions? Are you creating a tokenizer for a parser/compiler? Then you're better of doing it in layers: The parser extracts tokens from the tokenizer, the tokenizer extracts character from the stream, the stream extracts characters from the buffer, which in turn reads the characters from the file (or string, in the case of e.g. `std::istringstream`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are right, I'm writing a tokenizer. I want use a stream is because the `peek()` function is really handy for looking ahead tokens. I can implement this with vector or something else, I just want to know if the stream can do this.

Comment: The problem is that you still need to read individual characters from the file you're parsing. It's much simpler to create a tokenizer class which implements a suitable interface (with `get` and `peek` etc.) and have this class use the stream to read the characters.

Comment: With that said (and thanks for the remainder of @HolyBlackCat about `std::char_traits`) you can make your own `istream` class, either by specializing `std::basic_istream` for your token type or by inheritance. Then the stream could return `Token` structures, and read characters directly from the buffer. But it would be more complex, and there would be a lot of functionality that you might need to implement even if it's not going to be used. Creating a simple tokenizer class is really what I recommend.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, my lex use istream to handle every characters, I just want my tokens be a stream as well, I totally understand your suggestion and I'm gonna do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recipe for a way to create a custom stream object which can be done by inheriting `std::stringbuf`

```
class MyStreamBuf : public std::stringbuf {
//... override some functions from stringbuf (eg. sync) to change behavior
};

class MyInputStream : public std::istream {
  MyStreamBuf buf_;
public:
  MyInputStream : std::istream(&buf_){
  }

//... add more interface here, etc.

}
```

Continueing from that you should be able to acomplish what you asking for.